# How to handle the precedence of assignment operator in a PHP parser?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I wrote a PHP5 parser in ANTLR 3.4, which is almost ready, but I can not handle one of the tricky feature of PHP. My problem is with the precedence of assignment operator. As the PHP manual [says](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) the precedence of assignment is almost at the end of the list. Only `and`, `xor`, `or` and `,` are after it in the list.

But there is a note on this the manual page which says:

> Although `=` has a lower precedence than most other operators, PHP will
>   still allow expressions similar to the following: `if (!$a = foo())`, in
>   which case the return value of `foo()` is put into `$a`.

The small example in the note isn't a problem for my parser, I can handle this as a special case in the assigment rule.

But there are more complex codes eg:

`if ($a && $b = func()) {}`

My parser fails here, because it recognizes first `$a && $b` and can not deal with the rest of the conditioin. This is because the `&&` has higher precedence, than `=`.
If I put brackets around the right side of `&&`:

`if ($a && ($b = func())) {}`

In this way the parser recognizes the structure well.

The operators are built in the way that the ANTLR book recommends: there are the base exressions at the first step and each level of operators are coming after each other.

Is there any way to handle this precedence jumping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't look at it as an assignment, but let's name it an ***assignment expression***. Put this ***assignment expression*** "below" the unary expressions (so they have a higher precedence than the unary ones):

```java
grammar T;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  BLOCK;
  FUNC_CALL;
  EXPR_LIST;
}

parse
 : stat* EOF!
 ;

stat
 : assignment ';'!
 | if_stat
 ;

assignment
 : Var '='^ expr
 ;

if_stat
 : If '(' expr ')' block -> ^(If expr block)
 ;

block
 : '{' stat* '}' -> ^(BLOCK stat*)
 ;

expr
 : or_expr
 ;

or_expr
 : and_expr ('||'^ and_expr)*
 ;

and_expr
 : unary_expr ('&&'^ unary_expr)*
 ;

unary_expr
 : '!'^ assign_expr
 | '-'^ assign_expr
 | assign_expr
 ;

assign_expr
 : Var ('='^ atom)*
 | atom
 ;

atom
 : Num
 | func_call
 ;

func_call
 : Id '(' expr_list ')' -> ^(FUNC_CALL Id expr_list)
 ;

expr_list
 : (expr (',' expr)*)? -> ^(EXPR_LIST expr*)
 ;

If    : 'if';
Num   : '0'..'9'+;
Var   : '$' Id;
Id    : ('a'..'z')+;
Space : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();};
```

If you'd now parse the source:

```php
if (!$a = foo()) { $a = 1 && 2; }
if ($a && $b = func()) { $b = 2 && 3; }
if ($a = baz() && $b) { $c = 3 && 4; }
```

the following AST would get constructed:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't make a separate rule for the assigment as a statement. I think this was the missing piece.